# How do I set the refer-to column value in Lobos?

Tags: clojure, database-migration

Using Lobos, my migrations look like:

```
(defmigration company-table
  (up [] (create
          (tbl :companies
               (text name))))
  (down [] (drop
            (table :companies))))

(defmigration document-table
  (up [] (create
          (tbl :documents
               (timestamp :date_of_event)
               (text :title)
               (text :name)
               (refer-to :companies))))
  (down [] (drop
            (table :documents))))
```

I'd like to set the refer-to on documents s.t. the referring column name is company_id, e.g. `(refer-to :companies as :company_id)`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the [documentation](http://budu.github.io/lobos/doc/uberdoc.frontend.html) is that great, but there are two ways to do this:

- Using the `foreign-key` function

---

```
(defmigration document-table
  (up [] (create
          (table :documents
               (timestamp :date_of_event)
               (text :title)
               (text :name)
               (foreign-key :company-id :companies))))
;; or, if you need to specify options, you'd use something like this
               (foreign-key :company-id :companies :on-delete :cascade))))
```

- Using the `[:refer tname & options]` option.

---

```
(defmigration document-table
  (up [] (create
          (table :documents
               (timestamp :date_of_event)
               (text :title)
               (text :name)
               (integer :company-id [:refer companies]))))
;; or, if you need to specify options, you'd use something like this
               (integer :company-id [:refer companies :on-delete :cascade]))))
```

**Edit:** Also, unless you defined your own function `tbl`, you probably mean `table`

**Edit 2:** It looks like the documentation [here](http://budu.github.io/lobos/documentation.html) is much better.